# Filebeat doesn't read full event if empty line is in between

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

I currently try to read EVTX (windows event) files with Filebeat. This works so far, but of my almost 9.000 event entries only five aren't read. The problem here is the first line doesn't match my pattern (which might be because of the pattern itself) and the other four have empty lines in between.

My current lines look like that:

```
"Test message which represents the first line of

my current data
block

as shown here"; "Some value"; "More values"; "IDKFA"; "IDDQD"; "EndOfData"
```

What I did is using the multiline codec from Filebeat like this:

```
multiline.pattern: '^\".*EndOfData\"$'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: before
```

Every line ends with "EndOfData" at the end of the data block. 
The problem I have is, that Filebeat creates a completely new entry for every data line which is not empty. Like this:

**Entry #1:**

```
"Test message which represents the first line of
```

**Entry #2:**

```
my current data
block
```

**Entry #3:**

```
as shown here"; "Some value"; "More values"; "IDKFA"; "IDDQD"; "EndOfData"
```

It really doesn't work and I don't know why. The only difference to other entries is, that there are no spaces in between the lines. If I try to "ignore" the lines with the exclude_lines command and the regex such as "^$" it doesn#t work either.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `multiline.pattern: '^.*\"EndOfData\"$'`

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, that I still have three different entries for one data block with spaces in between and the ^\" in the start of my pattern means, that the whole data block starts with a quote and ends with the "EndOfData" tag. This works for whole blocks which do not have any spaces in between.

Comment: Ok, well if it starts with a quote " and ends with `EndOfData"` then the only problem is that this dot meta-character here `.` does not include newlines. Normally I would say _'Add an inline modifier (?s)'_ but,  I don't know your regex engine or if it supports that. The other option is to describe a character class with all of one kind and the inverse of that kind. The result is the class will match any character. Most engines will work with this. `^\"[\S\s]*?EndOfData\"$'` Take note of `[\S\s]*?` which is now _non-greedy_.